# Given an even number of vertices, how to find an optimum set of pairs based on proximity?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, 3d

The problem:

- We have a set of n vertices in 3D euclidean space, and there is an even number of these vertices.
- We want to pair them up based on their proximity. In other words, we'd like to be able to find a set of vertex pairs, where the vertices in each pair are as close as possible together.
- We want to minimise sacrificing the proximity between the vertices of any other pairs as much as possible in doing this.
- I am not looking for *the most* optimal solution (if it even strictly exists/can be done), just a reasonable one that can be computed relatively quickly.

A relatively awful brute force approach involves choosing a vertex and looping through the rest to find its nearest neighbor and then repeating until there are none left. Of course as we near the end of the list the closest vertex could be very far away, but it is the only choice, therefore this can fail badly on the third point above.

Comment: To be clear: you're trying to (approximately) minimize the total length of the edges between these pairs? Or the squared sum, or something?

Comment: Who is 'We'? What strategies have you tried so far?

Comment: @Dougal: Yes that sounds about right. However I should stress that we want to also minimise the chances of disproportionately large distances between *any* pairs if possible.

Comment: Sounds like a variation of the bin packing problem.

Comment: The problem of minimizing the sum of the edge distances between matched pairs is called the euclidean matching problem. [Here's](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall08/cps234/projects/sayan_proj.pdf) a short survey of results known for this problem.

Comment: Saying "I want to minimize X. But wait! I also want to minimize Y" is not a well-defined problem: you need to find a single parameter to optimize.  Perhaps you want to minimize the maximum distance between pairs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common approach for this kind of problems (especially if n is large) is to precompute a spatial index structure, such as a [kd tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or an [octtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) and perform the search for [nearest neighbors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) with the help of it. Through the nodes of the octtree, the available point are put into bins, so you can be sure they are mutually close. Also you minimize the number of comparisons.

A sketch of the implementation with an octtree: you need a Node class that stores its bounding box. A derived LeafNode class stores small number of points up to a maximum (e.g. k = 20), that are added with an insert function. A derived NonLeafNode class stores references to 8 subnodes (which may be both Leaf and NonLeafNodes).

The tree is represented by a root node, all insertions and queries start here. The tree is built up by starting with the first k points being inserted into a LeafNode. If the k+1st point is inserted, the bounding box is split into 8 sub boxes and the contained points are sorted into them. The current LeafNode is replaced by one NonLeafNode with 8 subnodes. 
This is iterated until all points are in the tree.

For nearest neighbor searches, the tree is traversed starting from the root node by comparing with the bounding box. If the query point is within a node's bounding box, the traversal goes into that node. Note that if you found the nearest candidate, you also need to check with neighboring nodes in the octtree.

For a kdtree implementation check the wikipedia page, looks quite straigthforward.

Comment: Upvoted, this could be the answer. Could you please expand on this a bit though?

Comment: +1 - This is a good idea too, thanks. I ended up accepting this since it's actually quite fast computationally as well as generating a good set of pairs.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are not looking for an optimal solution, here's a heuristic you may consider.

For each point p compute two points: the nearest neighbour and the farthest neighbour that are closest and farthest to p respectively. Now let q be the point with the largest farthest neighbour (q is an extreme point in the input). Match q with its nearest neighbour, delete both of them and recursively compute the matching for the remaining points.

This is certainly NOT optimal, but it does seem to do reasonably well on small input sets. If you need an optimal solution you should read about the [euclidean matching problem](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall08/cps234/projects/sayan_proj.pdf).